# DNS Problem with Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, dns

I cannot use the browser and internet connection in my android app with android simulator.

When I try to open a homepage using the native webbrowser in the emulator, but when I use the ip address, it opens just fine.

How can I fix DNS problems in the android Emulator.

I already turned off the Windows Firewall, but it didn't work.

Data: Windows 7 x64 / Eclipse Plugin for Android / Android version 2.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have multiple NICs on your machine?  The emulator might be trying to use a DNS that it cannot access (i.e. going through the wired DNS server if wired is disconnected).  You can check which DNS server is being used by starting the emulator with the `-debug-slirp` flag.

See [here](http://blog.creativeworkline.com/2010/03/android-emulator-cannot-resolve-dns.html) for more info.

Comment: Yes. That worked. After checking my DNS Server, I could specify my DNS server for the Android Emulator.
Thanks!

Comment: I have tried to pass the settings to the emulator with -dns-server 8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4 and nothing. I can us to ip addresses directly, but not domain names.

Comment: @abellina did you ever fix that issue. experiencing the same.